# Count of missing observations in variable

Tags: r

I want to get the count of NA's in column with max and min. is there any way in expss already to get a count  in below example

```
library(expss)
library(dplyr)



df <- mtcars
df$hp[df$hp<75]=NA

df$vs <- 1
banner1 <- list(df$vs)

Min <- function(x) min_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
Max <- function(x) max_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
t1 <- cross_fun(df, df$hp, col_vars = banner1, 
                      fun = combine_functions(Max = Max, Min = Min, `Valid N` = valid_n))
```

Expected output should include missing values with max and min from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a small custom function to get the count of NAs you could do:

```r
library(expss)

df <- mtcars
df$hp[df$hp < 75] <- NA

df$vs <- 1
banner1 <- list(df$vs)

Min <- function(x) min_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
Max <- function(x) max_col(x, na.rm = TRUE)
cross_fun(df, df$hp,
  col_vars = banner1,
  fun = combine_functions(
    Max = Max, 
    Min = Min, 
    `Valid N` = valid_n,
    `NA` = \(x) sum(is.na(x)))
) |> 
  print()
#>                           
#>  |       |         |   1 |
#>  | ----- | ------- | --- |
#>  | df$hp |     Max | 335 |
#>  |       |     Min |  91 |
#>  |       | Valid N |  27 |
#>  |       |      NA |   5 |
```